# phpmailer not working when I pull the code from repository

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a problem with phpmailer.
I have create a simple appointment form so that the user can create a appointment and receive a confirmation of his/her appointment in inbox. I use the phpmailer.

The code work perfectly on my laptop. I commit the working code to the repository. When I pull the code to the organization server, the working code is not sending mail to my email.

Below are the specification the machines specification on my laptop:
PopOS (Linux machine)
Apache server: 2.4.46
PHP version 7.4.9
PHPmailer

specification organization server:
windows server 2012R2
xampp php: 5.6.8
xampp version: 3.21

Comment: Your production server uses XAMPP?  Yikes.  Regardless, "works on my PC" is a common problem in software development - that means it doesn't work.  There are a ton of possible issues/solutions for "mail doesn't send from my server" so I would recommend googling for that.

Comment: Xampp is not the production server. its the company test server

Comment: which transport you are using for sending mails from laptop? via SMTP login or Sendmail?

Comment: I am using the SMTP login

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a valid question for Stack Overflow. Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpmailer+local+server) and [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) which cover this exact topic. You should not be using those old versions of PHP, certainly not for new development; 5.6 is years out of data and is now positively dangerous. There have been *10 releases* of 7.4 since 7.4.9, including security patches, so your server is vulnerable too.